# Getting Error -> SequelizeDatabaseError: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'create' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, reactjs

This is a weird error. To set the background: I've built a React app utilizing SQL Server some months ago. Abandoned the project and now am resurrecting it. When last visited, everything worked fine. I could enter and retrieve data from the database. Project was saved to GitHub. Now I'm revisiting it and I'm having trouble getting data into the database. I had to rebuild my MAC (2019 MBA) and the database. Here is the table structure (the SQL file to create the database same that initially created it back months ago, this is just the portion for the offending table):

```
CREATE TABLE budgets (
  id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  clientid INT DEFAULT NULL,
  catitem varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  subcatitem varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  start_date varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  end_date varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  quantity INT DEFAULT 1,
  frequency VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  cost decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  createdAt date DEFAULT NULL,
  updatedAt date DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Here is the API call to store the data (React, Axios, Serialize):

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Save Budget to MSSQL database
    Budgets.create({
        clientid: req.body.clientid,
        catitem: req.body.catitem,
        subcatitem: req.body.subcatitem,
        start_date: req.body.startDate,
        end_date: req.body.endDate,
        quantity: req.body.quantity,
        frequency: req.body.frequency,
        cost: req.body.cost,
    }).then(budget => {
        // Send created budget to budgets
        res.send(budget);
    }).catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send("Error -> " + err);
    })
};
```

None of the code React code has changed. Here is my Postman URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/budgets/create?clientid=2&catitem='Business Services'&subcatitem='Concierge IT'&startDate='1/1/2020'&endDate='12/312020'&quantity=1&frequency='Monthly'&cost=1000.00
```

The error generated from Postman:

> Error -> SequelizeDatabaseError: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'create' to data type int.

Running an INSERT script in Azure Data Studio is successful. Any ideas what would be causing this error?

Comment: *"Here is the sql statement sent to the api via Postman"* That isn't a SQL statement, it's a URL.

Comment: L a r n u... Please.

Comment: Larnu is saying we need to understand how your API takes a request and translates it into a SQL statement, so we/you can compare that to the statement that works in Azure Data Studio. Without that, how are your peers supposed to guess why the statement you haven't shown us is failing? `create` seems to be the method/interface name so unless you can show us how that word gets into the statement (because it doesn't appear anywhere else in the Postman URL), we can't guess.

Comment: Considering that the value erroring is `'create'` this suggests that *either* the `create` in your URL (after `/budgets/`) is being parsed as the first parameter, for `clientid`, or that you have something like a `TRIGGER` that is generating said error.

Answer (score 0):

So figured out what was happening in Postman to generate the error. I was sending the request with a GET insetead of a POST. Now it's posting a new record to the table except that it only contains the auto-generated fields (id, createdAt, and updatedAT). The passed in values don't get posted.?

Comment: So all is well in Idiotsville. For some reason I had gone in an changed a data type of one of the db fields from varchar to int and that was causing the failure.